# Google calendar has an event that is stuck and cannot be deleted

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have been using the Google Calendar API with PHP to create events and I got the following error after trying to create an event:

> Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/mycalendar_nrfo11fd4vi2a83ir85b8b2rp0%40group.calendar.google.com/events:
>   (409) The requested identifier already exists.

I then searched in Google Calendar to see if the event exists and it showed this result:

[image]

I can't seem to do anything with this event, I can't find any option to delete it. Anyone know how I can get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to calendar.google.com and sign-in with your account. Upon right-clicking the event, there should be an option to either DELETE or REMOVE the event.